# Использование JavaScript в Qt

Tags: javascript, c++, qtcreator

Существуют ли такие задачи, когда использование скрипта в Qt прям именно то что нужно? Что весомого дают такие возможности? Не могу осознать необходимость такой фичи

Comment: QML посмотрите. Там почти Javascript. Используется для быстрого создания GUI.

Comment: @Semerkin Вы про QtScript ? Он нужен если Вы хотите встроить интерпретатор  в своё Qt приложение. Для примера  редактор Daz3D. Редактор написан на Qt , а сценарии для этого редактора пишутся на QtScript .

Comment: Я правильно понял основную мысль в том, что вся это скриптовщина для работы с GUI only?

Comment: Эту "необходимость" изобрела Nokia, по сути создав ещё один GUI внутри Qt. Они хотели облегчить написание программ для Meego, но в результате разорились :(